# Listing post from custom post type category?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type and a taxonomy for portfolio created like this:

```
    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Portfolio', 'my-portfolio'),
        'labels' => array(
            'add_new_item' => __('New portfolio', 'my-portfolio'),
            'new_item' => __('New portfolio', 'my-portfolio'),
            'not_found' => __('No portfolio items', 'my-portfolio'),
        ),
        'singular_label' => __('Portfolio', 'my-portfolio'),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-portfolio',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false),
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_remove_metaboxes_portfolio',
       );

    //Register type and custom taxonomy for type.
    register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );
    register_taxonomy("portfolio-category", array("portfolio"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Categories", "singular_label" => "Category", "rewrite" => true, "slug" => 'portfolio-category',"show_in_nav_menus"=>false));
```

This works like it should when I use it in my queries. And it shows in the menu in backend, along with the categories for this custom post type.

My issue is when I try to retrieve all the post from a certain category (by clicking on the category name) I get `No posts were found. Sorry!` on my page.

The page is a default wordpress archive that should just list all the posts, but nothing is showing. The url is like this:

`http://xampp/my-theme/?portfolio-category=animals`

But even if I use post-name permalinks nothing works.

I've read on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/make-archives-php-include-custom-post-types/) that I could use this function in `functions.php`

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
  if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
     'post', 'portfolio', 'nav_menu_item'
        ));
      return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

But this doesn't help either. What am I missing here?

Comment: Set hierarchical to false in your cpt if are not going to use parent-child relationship.

Comment: I'll probably use the parent-child relationship, something like display all the parent categories, then when you go into one you can see child categories and posts within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use archive page templates for your custom post type. And Please put the code in custom post type

```
$args = array(
        'label' => __('Portfolio', 'my-portfolio'),
        'labels' => array(
            'add_new_item' => __('New portfolio', 'my-portfolio'),
            'new_item' => __('New portfolio', 'my-portfolio'),
            'not_found' => __('No portfolio items', 'my-portfolio'),
        ),
        'singular_label' => __('Portfolio', 'my-portfolio'),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-portfolio',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false),
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_remove_metaboxes_portfolio',
       );

    //Register type and custom taxonomy for type.
    register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Comment: Do not use `flush_rewrite_rules()` in the way you have done it. Itnis extremely expensive to run and hard on resources. It slows page loads down a lot

Comment: without flush_rewrite_rules how can be possible to call page templates?

Comment: Do it once and remove it. The codex lists the hooks in which it should be used

Comment: What did you do different than what I wrote? Except the `flush_rewrite_rules();`

Comment: Nothing you have to do it for calling custom post type templates.

Comment: I read the documentation now, and basically I only need to do it on plugin activation/deactivation. Well thanks for pointing this out :)